# Improving expression with integer multiplications and modulo

Tags: java, optimization, integer, bit-manipulation, modulo

Is there a way, I can write the following line, that is more efficient than the current expression?

```
Math.abs(((a*k + b) % P) % m);
```

`P` is a constant prime number
`m` is non negative and a power of 2
`a` and `b` are random non negative numbers

**Note:** To be clear, this is not a hot spot I found during profiling and I want to improve. My interest is in finding if there is a way to write the expression better (in terms of efficiency) that might be known easily to someone with a better background in bit operations for example.

Comment: If your code works and you are asking for improvement then you should probably ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Pshemo:Is that SE also for optimization questions or only for code style/design approaches?

Comment: Are `P` and `m` anything useful or just some random values?

Comment: If P and m are constants there are optimisations one can apply, otherwise no there isn't anything.

Comment: From what I remember your question could be asked with `performance` tag. Only problem with it is that it should be used *only if and where optimization is needed*.

Comment: @harold:`P` is a big prime number. `m` is a power of size 2 currently. This is just an implementation of universal hashing

Comment: @Cratylus OK power is two is good, then you can write `& (m - 1)` instead of `% m` (well, most of the time - that works if the left operand is non-negative)

Comment: @Voo:`P` is indeed a constant which is a prime number.

Comment: @harold:1)Would that replace the `Math.abs`? 2) If `m` was a prime number would such a conversion be available?

Comment: Maybe assign the value to a variable - `res = ((a*k + b) % P) % m);` and then `if (res < 0) res = 0 - res`. It will prevent calling a method, but you'll have to profile it to see if it realy makes a difference.

Comment: And modulo by a constant should be optimized by the JIT compiler anyway, you could do it by hand but it would look very ugly unless the constant is a power of two

Comment: @harold:No it is a prime

Comment: Well wait, can `a * k + b` be negative?

Comment: @harold:Yes as `k` can be negative and `a` and `b` are random

Comment: Ok, and does that `abs` actually matter or is that just a way to force the number to be non-negative? Because anything `& (m - 1)` is non-negative (unless `m == 0`), but in a different way than if you had `abs`ed it

Comment: @harold:What do you mean by `in a different way than if you had absed it`? And `m != 0` always

Comment: @Cratylus for example it would map -1 to a big number (`m - 1` actually), instead of to 1

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the comment chain, you could write

```
(a * k + b) % P & (m - 1)
```

which is **not** equivalent to the original expression, but meets the same requirements anyway. It handles the case that `a * k + b` is negative (either because `k` is negative or because of wrapping) differently, but in a way that is still fine for a hash function.

In this new expression, the only remaining mod-operation is by a constant, which any respectable compiler optimizes along the same lines as it optimizes division by a constant.

Comment: 1) My only concern is if the fact that `is not equivalent to the original expression` could have some kind of negative impact as this is a universal hash function 2) Is there *any* kind of change *if* `m` were a prime as well?

Comment: @Cratylus if `m` is not a power of two, the whole `& (m - 1)` deal breaks down horribly. But with a PoT `m` there shouldn't be any negative consequences, the negatives are just "mirrored", it doesn't affect the evenness of the distribution at all. And actually, in some sense it may even be "more correct", since the hashing math is always unsigned (so really, the `%` should be an `Integer.remainderUnsigned`)

Answer (score 1):

This gets a similar answer ("similar" means "same result when bracketed expression is non-negative, but different when negative), but using bit kung fu to avoid the modulus division *and* the call to `Math.abs()`:

```
(a*k + b) % P & ~-m
```

To see what's going on, let's assume `m = 8` and have a look at the 16-bit bit patterns:

```
8   -> 0000 1000
-8  -> 1111 1000
~-8 -> 0000 0111
```

As you can see, `~-m` produces the bit mask you need to mask off all but the bits needed for the result of `n % m` - ie the high bit (negative indicator bit) and all but the bits to the right of the 1 bit used for the power of 2 number.

On a personal note, I am quite enamoured with the expression `~-m`, which when ANDed with the preceding calculation achieves both the `abs()` (by bit-masking off the high bit) and effectively does a modulus division when `m` is a power of two.

The difference arises when the preceding result is negative, due to this approach treating negative as if they were positive.

Comment: Btw, `~-m == (m - 1)`.

Comment: @harold yes, I assumed it would be faster, however I just did a test and `~-m` is about 20% slower than `m - 1`. This may still be of use to someone who wants to solve a puzzler that denied the use of subtraction.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't expected any difference (aren't compilers supposed to know this identity?)

Comment: @harold it's not an identity; it's only true for powers of 2

Comment: It's actually always true, because `-x == ~(x - 1)` and thus its inversion is just plain `x - 1`.